# PowerShell WMI filter on variable

Tags: powershell, wmi

This is not the exact scenario of what I'm trying to accomplish but is a good example of where I am stuck.

```
$Path = "\\192.168.1.1\config"
Get-CimInstance -Namespace ROOT\CIMV2 -ClassName Win32_MappedLogicalDisk -Filter "ProviderName=$Path"
```

This produces an "Invalid Query" error as it's trying to use `\\` in the query

I know I can do this manually by using:

```
Get-CimInstance -Namespace ROOT\CIMV2 -ClassName Win32_MappedLogicalDisk -Filter "ProviderName='`\\`\\192.168.1.1`\\config'"
```

This doesn't solve my problem as I need to pass the value from a variable

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I also don't want to query the whole class and then filter after. e.g. `Get-CimInstance -Namespace ROOT\CIMV2 -ClassName Win32_MappedLogicalDisk | where {$_.ProviderName -eq $Path}` as it will slow down the script massively

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do an inline replace to escape the backslashes:

```
$Path = "\\192.168.1.1\config"
Get-CimInstance -Namespace ROOT\CIMV2 -ClassName Win32_MappedLogicalDisk -Filter "ProviderName='$($Path -replace '\\','\\')'"
```

Note: Don't forget to put single quotes around the value part of the filter.

`$()` is the subexpression [operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7). Since `-replace` uses regex, a single `\` must also be escaped for the match expression.